# How does user activity affect entropy generation process in GnuPG?

Tags: passwords, gnupg, key-generation, entropy

Earlier today, I was using `gpg` to generate keys for work. While doing so, I noticed:

> We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to
> perform some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse,
> utilize the disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random
> number generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.

How does user activity affect the entropy generation process in GnuPG?

Comment: The process uses the entropy from the randomness of the user's mouse movements and key presses.  See https://www.bitaddress.org/ for a good example of how this works in real time.